# Reverse proxy in python 3

Tags: python, proxy

I need a simple reverse proxy for Python 3.

I like Twisted and its simple reverse http proxy (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.1/_downloads/reverse-proxy.py) ...

```
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

"""
This example demonstrates how to run a reverse proxy.

Run this example with:
    $ python reverse-proxy.py

Then visit http://localhost:8080/ in your web browser.
"""

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server

site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('www.yahoo.com', 80, ''))
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

.... but it throws error in Python 3.

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 571, in dataReceived
    why = self.lineReceived(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1752, in lineReceived
    self.allContentReceived()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1845, in allContentReceived
    req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 766, in requestReceived
    self.process()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 185, in process
    resrc = self.site.getResourceFor(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 791, in getResourceFor
    return resource.getChildForRequest(self.resource, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/resource.py", line 98, in getChildForRequest
    resource = resource.getChildWithDefault(pathElement, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/resource.py", line 201, in getChildWithDefault
    return self.getChild(path, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web/proxy.py", line 278, in getChild
    self.host, self.port, self.path + b'/' + urlquote(path, safe=b"").encode('utf-8'),
builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Is there something similar that works in python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this simple package on pypi, it seems to be working well and it is similarly simple.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/maproxy

Answer (score 4):

Having stumbled into this problem myself, I was disappointed to find no answer here. After some digging, I was able to get it working by changing the `path` argument in `proxy.ReverseProxyResource` to `bytes` rather than `str`, rendering the following line:

```
site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource("www.yahoo.com", 80, b''))
```

This is necessary because twisted appends a trailing slash as `bytes` (ie `b'/'`) internally.